# Regex to match text longer than x characters between html tags?

Tags: html, regex, preg-match

I have the task of migrating THE worst HTML product descriptions you will ever encounter. It consists of a mixture of tables and paragraphs. The majority are not even 100% valid HTML and there are plenty of Microsoft tags courtesy of MS Word. It is littered with in line style tags and the most of it relies on the most bonky set of css rules you will ever see.

Essentially I have come the the realisation that the only thing of use is the paragraphs of text. I can not just grab the `<p>` tags as sometimes the paragraphs do not use them and sometimes titles or single words have their own `<p>` tag.

So my question is can I match text that is longer then *x* characters between html tags?

Ideally it would also ignore `<br/>` and `<br>`

[Here is a link](http://www.towequipe.co.uk/products//754-869-1594-thule-aero-roof-bars-fits-skoda-octavia-iii-2009-on.html) to an example of the html I am dealing with

Note it is just the description I am processing, not the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group `1` of this regex will match `n+` chars between tags (n = `100` in this example):

```
<[^>]+>([^<]{100,})<[^>]+>
```

Notes:

- I have deliberately *not* matched for a matching closing tag (`<([^>]+)>([^<]{100,})<\1>`) because of OP's sloppy HTML - a tag is a tag
- I have avoided using a lookbehind (`(?<=<[^>]+>)`) because the match is of arbitrary length, which can cause backtracking problems (some languages, like java, do not even support it).

Comment: Is there anyway I can make it ignore <br> <strong> and <b> tags... so that they do not count as a closing or starting tag?

Comment: regex isn't a good tool for that kind of thing (I had a go using negative lookarounds, but couldn't get it to work). However just use your local language (I assume PHP, so `str_replace()` the tags with blank) to remove all such tags from your input before using regex. If you need to know where the tags were, replace `<br>` with `[br]` etc so they no longer match the regex, but will still be recognisable in the text

Answer (score 0):

Scanning through the site a little, it looks like many of the descriptions fall short of 100 characters.  You might try a multi-pass approach, where in the first iteration, you capture all content from the first table following '`div id="tab1"`'.  From that starting point, it may be easier to identify and eliminate the parts you ***don't*** want, rather than extracting the parts you do want.

Comment: I have access to just the description - just tab1... but still there is the problem of getting just the content out.